# Disable buttons in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am working with an input and output log in laravel 5.8
And I need that when the user clicks on the "register entry button" it is deactivated and the "register exit button" is activated. But I can't think how to do this, I'm pretty new to Laravel.

These are the buttons that I need to activate and deactivate respectively

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ setActive('Input_time.*') }}"
            href="{{ route('Input_time.index') }}"
            >@lang('Check in')
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ setActive('Departure_time.*') }}"
            href="{{ route('Departure_time.index') }}"
            >@lang('Check out')
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: You'll need some JS to toggle the state, but that being said, `<a>` elements do not support disabled. `<button>`s do, and you can add classes that make it look disabled, but you'll need custom logic to prevent navigation when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a simple snippet the rest you better know that what you want. You don't need to remove your laravel blade syntax. I have removed just for testing purposes.

**Answer Updated Check if this is what you want**

```js
$('.check_in').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({
    //"pointer-events": "none",
    "cursor": "no-drop"
  });
  $('.check_out').css({
    //"pointer-events": "",
    "cursor": ""
  });
  
  //$(this).closest('li').addClass('d-none');
  //$('.check_out').closest('li').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('.check_out').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({
    //"pointer-events": "none",
    "cursor": "no-drop"
  });
  $('.check_in').css({
    //"pointer-events": "",
    "cursor": ""
  });
  
  //$(this).closest('li').addClass('d-none');
  //$('.check_in').closest('li').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link check_in" href="#">Check In
        </a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link check_out" href="#">Check Out
        </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This would really work, but I tried adding it to my code and it doesn't do anything, I don't know if I'm wrong about something ...

Comment: Is it a side menu or horizontal menu ? can you clarify it more ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my "nav" file, because the buttons are in the navigation bar:

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link check_in {{ setActive('Input_time.*') }}"
            href="{{ route('Input_time.index') }}"
            >@lang('Check in')
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item d-none">
        <a class="nav-link check_out {{ setActive('Departure_time.*') }}"
            href="{{ route('Departure_time.index') }}"
            >@lang('Check out')
        </a>
    </li>
```

This to the file that joins the views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            @include('partials.nav')
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

And this to the javascript file:

```
$('.check_in').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('d-none');
  $('.check_out').closest('li').removeClass('d-none')
});

$('.check_out').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('d-none');
  $('.check_in').closest('li').removeClass('d-none')
});
```

But it does nothing.

Comment: Do not copy someone answer school kid.